# Apollo Client on React - How to retrieve the error message fomated?

Tags: react-apollo

I can't find info about it in anywhere...

Consider this very simple scenario...

```
<Mutation mutation={LOGIN_MUTATION}>
            {(login, { data, loading, error }) => {
                if (error) {
                    console.log(error)
                }
```

I am receiving a string error message like...

```
Error: GraphQL error: ERROR_INVALID_LOGIN_PROVIDER
at new ApolloError (bundle.umd.js:92)
at MutationData.onMutationCompleted (react-hooks.cjs.js:636)
at react-hooks.cjs.js:559
at tryCallOne (core.js:37)
at core.js:123
at JSTimers.js:289
at _callTimer (JSTimers.js:146)
at _callImmediatesPass (JSTimers.js:194)
at Object.callImmediates (JSTimers.js:458)
at MessageQueue.__callImmediates (MessageQueue.js:366)
```

I can't take actions based on the error message formated in this way. ERROR_INVALID_LOGIN_PROVIDER could be ERROR_INVALID_PASSWORD, for example... 
I need to take decisions based on the error messages. but I just receive a string containing the graphql error, the modules inside the js and a lot of information that's not important. Is there any way to receive the error message formatted imn a way that I can extract only the server error ?

Comment: is LOGIN_MUTATION take variables add try the error.message console

Comment: LOGIN_MUTATION is just a gql query

Comment: use the message to become error more readable Mutation mutation={LOGIN_MUTATION}>
            {(login, { data, loading, error }) => {
                if (error) {
                    console.log(error.message)
                }

Comment: u r really not understanding...sorry

Comment: try to used req.graphQlErrors[0].message or  req.graphQlErrors.map(ele=>ele.message)

Answer (score 1):

This should be possible

error in your example should be an [ApolloError](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/blob/06baaa1468de163b470010e1e88966f23bee1cce/packages/apollo-client/src/errors/ApolloError.ts#L33) with the possible [GraphQLErrors](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/blob/ed0dfe8afb92d942e20a9b254c87dee01181a0f3/src/error/GraphQLError.js#L16) or a NetworkError

```
(login, { data, loading, error }) => {
            if (error) {
                if (error.graphQlErrors && error.graphQLErrors.length > 0) {
                    // There are graphQL errors and there may be multiple but its always an array.
                    // You should handle it properly

                     const { message } = error.graphQLErrors[0]
                     console.log(message) // e.g. ERROR_INVALID_LOGIN_PROVIDER

                 } else if (error.networkError) {
                    // There may be a network error
                     const { message } = error.networkError
                     console.log(message) // e.g. NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.
                 }
        }
```

Comment: Will not work because error is not an object...as I said...it's a string containing all the things mentioned.